# How to draw a rectangle around an object using some openCV algorithm

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

I am working on object detection with opencv.
I want to draw a rectangle around an object after clicking on it by mouse.
What kind of technique can I use? I tried with SURF but in vain.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a hugely open question, and a complete solution is still an active area of research. You could look into thresholding or graphcut to get you started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What kind of images you want to use?
If the image is a sort of simple one(e.g. a pencil on white paper, a mark on plain wall), would you consider using following approach? I think it is very classical approach but works good when the situation is limited.

```
cv::Mat img = // your image.
double threshold = 128; // needs adjustment.
int n_erode_dilate = 1; // needs adjustment.

cv::Mat m = img.clone();
cv::cvtColor(m, m, CV_RGB2GRAY); // convert to glayscale image.
cv::blur(m, m, cv::Size(5,5));
cv::threshold(m, m, threshold, 255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
cv::erode(m, m, cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1,-1),n_erode_dilate);
cv::dilate(m, m, cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1,-1),n_erode_dilate);

std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
cv::findContours(m, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
for (size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++) {
        cv::Point p = contours[i][j];
        points.push_back(p);
    }
}
// And process the points or contours to pick up specified object.

// for example: draws rectangle on original image.
if(points.size() > 0){
    cv::Rect brect = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(points).reshape(2));
    cv::rectangle(img, brect.tl(), brect.br(), cv::Scalar(100, 100, 200), 2, CV_AA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My best advice would be to detect the object first using some OpenCV image processing techniques such as..... Threshold to binaries your image, use blur it to enhance edges detection, use canny filter perhaps erode and dilation.

Once you get a decent threshold where your ROI's stand out from the background I would use a function called findcontours to get the contours of all blobs present in your image, if you get some unwonted contours you could specifies to only draw contour if the are is bigger than X.

Once you have the contours of the ROI's stored (in a vector) next step would be to draw bounding boxes around these contours using Rect function.

OpenCV is a very open field for every problem there is plenty of solutions or paths you could choose to take. I would highly recommend to visit [OpenCv Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/)

But first check the version of the opencv you have installed or using

Answer (score 0):

An object has to be detected first before you can find its bounding rectangle.  By clicking on the object you only specify a pixel that belongs to the object. That's not enough because you know nothing about the shape of the object. So clicking on the object does not equal object detection.

How you detect an object depends on the application.  One way to find the object's outline (edges) is by segmentation. Look into [watershed](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=watershed#void%20watershed%28InputArray%20image,%20InputOutputArray%20markers%29) or [grabcut](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grabcut#void%20grabCut%28InputArray%20img,%20InputOutputArray%20mask,%20Rect%20rect,%20InputOutputArray%20bgdModel,%20InputOutputArray%20fgdModel,%20int%20iterCount,%20int%20mode%29) segmentation algorithms in OpenCV. It will give you a contour of the object (if the object stands out from its background). In general, a method for object detection depends on the application, and it's an active research area. Knowing what kind of object is being detected can greatly aid in detection and segmentation.

Once you have the object's contour you can find its bounding rectangle using [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#boundingrect) function. Drawing the rectangle is easy, just use [rectangle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=rectangle#rectangle) function.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is rather simple and in one color, you can try to use the [watershed algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#watershed). It should work fine for one color objects like pencil but definitely will fail in more complex situations.

Answer (score 0):

after cvtColor erode dilate

```
// get the contours
std::vector< std::vector< cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(imageMat, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

// http://blog.csdn.net/corcplusplusorjava/article/details/20536251
// draw contours
cv::drawContours(imageMat , allContours ,-1 , cv::Scalar(0) , 2) ;
```